# Using tags with picturebox in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am practicing C# programming and I am following a tutorial I found online. I found an interest in Ms Visual Studio and have been self-teaching at the moment. I have done my own edits from the tutorial but have been as close as the tutorial as possible. Everything seems fine except there is a part in the code that I just cant figure out no matter what I do or research. In the tutorial it made me create I think 30 pictureboxes. Each picturebox is tagged a word-name like blocks or bricks or however you choose. I presume it's to make it easier to do if/else statements with all the pictureboxes at once instead of one at a time. I understand It would be less time consuming to just say "if pictureboxes have the tag "bricks" then do XYZ.
Anyway, I followed the code to the T but visualbasic is saying

"Possible unintended reference comprarison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Here's the part of code that this giving me this

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {
            if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "blockies")
            {
                if (pBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                {
                    this.Controls.Remove(x);
                    pBally = -pBally;
                    score++;
                }
            }
        }
```

It has a green squiggly line from x.Tag to blockies"
Thanks for any help.
ps. Windows Form

Comment: `but visualbasic is saying` where is that VB code?

Comment: It's saying pretty much the above in quotes.

Comment: I see it, but there is nothing related with VB. it is c#

Comment: Sorry I meant this to just be Windows Form C# using VS 2017

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Tag` is not a string. You need to do `x.Tag.ToString() == "blockies"` instead:

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
    if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == "blockies")
    {
        if (pBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(x);
            pBally = -pBally;
            score++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.Control.Tag.get returned null.

Comment: @Razgr1z Check that `x.Tag != null` before calling `ToString()`. Your tag is null when that happens. I've edited my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

I find *using Linq* more readable.

Fixing your issues with comparison warning and problem of *removing an element from a collection while enumerating on it* :

```
foreach(var pb in this.Controls
                    .OfType<PictureBox>()
                    .Where(x => (string)x.Tag == "blockies")
                    .Where(x => pBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                    .ToList())
{
    this.Controls.Remove(pb);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! Unfortunately when I use this code the picture boxes start diappearing all at once. I should have stated in the beginning that I am making a block game with this type of code. Is there anything else I should provide to fix? Thanks

Comment: When I added your code the ''ball'' didn't bounce back anymore.

Comment: @Razgr1z  this code is similar to one you posted in question and fixes it.  You ask different things now and I don't know your code and if you have a logical error or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the [**Control.Tag**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx), you will see the definition of it.

```
public object Tag { get; set; }
```

You are trying to compare object to string, so this error message is shown.

What you should do is:

```
if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag.ToString() == "blockies")
```

Another point you should try to avoid arrow code structure, it is really hard to read:

```
    foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
    {
        if (!(x is PictureBox))
           continue;

        //this is needed if you want to use some specific property of the PictureBox.
        PictureBox ctl = (PictureBox)x;

        if(ctl.Tag.ToString() != "blockies")
            continue;

        if (!pBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ctl.Bounds))
             continue;

         //Also this line will create you a problem, because you will change the Control collection 
         //when you try to enumerate it. This should throw you an exception. Better make the control not visible.
         //this.Controls.Remove(x);

         x.Visible = false;

         pBally = -pBally;
         score++;
    }
```

In this case you have better readability of the code.

Comment: Not my downvotes but your triple `continues`  probably are not to everyone's taste.